# Elastic Beanstalk and Private GitHub repos

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install

What is the recommended way to use Elastic Beanstalk for a node web app (express) where it depends on private node modules from GitHub?  I know how to generate ssh keys that can be used as deploy keys with GitHub but that requires me to login to the EB box which defeats the goal of being able to autoscale as demand increases.  I've tried doing an upload of the entire web app with the node modules already included but it appears to still to try and run an npm install and fail in that situation.

Comment: Are you allowed to use jenkins or another ci tool?

Comment: If you can use CI/CD tools, use them to build the application and pull in any private modules, package everything up as a zip file and push to S3, you can then deploy everything from that zip file on EB, without the need to touch the instance. Personally I use Codeship which already has built in connectors for EB S3 etc.., but there will be other options.

Comment: We use DockerHub and Jenkins to do this. DockerHub watches the GitHub repo, builds an image on code push. Jenkins listens for a message from DockerHub, and when it gets it, it runs an eb deploy.